# Incrementation to a list's for method

Tags: python, list, sum

I am trying to implement an incrementation to a previously defined variable called *sum*.

```
return [sum = sum + number for number in range(a,b)]
```

Of course this format brings up error but using the similar:

```
return [sum = number for number in range(a,b)]
```

The code is faulty but runs. If there's a way to implement it and return sum the code would work.

And also if someone could inform me about the nomenclature I'd forever be grateful.

Comment: `sum()` is a built-in function in Python, and it basically does what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What Havenard said. Otherwise, I think you want the cumulative sum. See `accumulate` in the itertools module.

Comment: The code that you posted is invalid and will _not_ run. You cannot have an assignment in a list comprehension.

Comment: `print(sum(range(0,  3)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few possible answers. What you are using is called a `list comprehension`.

```
s += (b*(b-1) - a*(a-1))//2

s += sum([n for n in range(a,b)])

for n in range(a,b):
    s += n
```

It's not a good idea to name a variable `sum` as it is a built in Python function.

Comment: Your first option is obviously the fastest. But your second option can be simplified to `sum(range(a, b))`. Also, you can pass `sum` a generator 
expression instead of a list comprehension, eg `sum(n for n in range(a,b))`, which saves using RAM to create a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
return sum([number for number in range(a,b)])
```

As said in the commentaries, `sum` is a python built-in function which, given an array, it returns the result of the addtion of all elements in it

Comment: No reason to use a list comprehension here. You're holding all the values at once in memory when you don't need to; just use a generator expression. Just change the brackets to an extra set of parentheses and your program will thank you for it :)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds You don't even need the extra parentheses here, since the gen exp is the only arg being passed to `sum`.

Comment: Do you have a list/tutorial/guide/book to recommend with those little python tricks to optimize code?

Comment: You can Google/YouTube around for things about iterators and generators and such, but IMO the easiest way to learn it is to try and implement it. The first time I defined an `__iter__` was on a linked list class that I created, and it really helped solidify it for me.  I'd recommend Raymond Hettinger's PyCon 2013 talk "Transforming code into beautiful idiomatic Python." (Though it is an old talk now).

Answer (score 0):

You essentially reimplemented the built-in function `sum`. Just call the function directly:

```
return sum(range(a, b))
```